# Add footer to Java iTextPdf 7 with page number

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, itext7

I am trying to add footer containing username on the left and page number of total pages on the right
I am using iTextPdf 7 on Java but I am not able to find any useful way to do that
please find below my code
The import :

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
```

small sample of the code :

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(path);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
pdfDocument.addNewPage();
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
Paragraph dateParagraph = new Paragraph(todayDate.toString());
dateParagraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
document.add(dateParagraph);
document.close();
```

footer sample :

[this is sample for the needed footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rt07.png)

Comment: What do you mean by `page number of total pages`? What do you expect to see in the footer (please provide examples)?

Comment: Do you need the current page number, total number of pages or both?

Comment: I have added sample footer, I need to do something exactly the same as in the sample

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example that does the job. There are numerous ways of adding footers with page numbers in iText and depending on your context one way might be more suitable than the others. The sample I provide is a good start:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, false);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        document.add(new AreaBreak());
    }
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));
}

int totalPages = document.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getPageNumber();

for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    Paragraph footer = createFooter(totalPages);
    footer.setFixedPosition(i, 40, 40, 300);
    document.add(footer);
}

document.close();
```

Note that I am using `Paragraph` as a footer element but you can use `Table` or anything else really:

```
private Paragraph createFooter(int totalPages) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    Text currentPage = new Text("");
    currentPage.setNextRenderer(new CurrentPageNumberRenderer(currentPage));
    p.add("Page ").add(currentPage).add(" of ").add(new Text(String.valueOf(totalPages)));
    return p;
}
```

Here is our custom renderer that will assign page number dynamically:

```
private static class CurrentPageNumberRenderer extends TextRenderer {
    public CurrentPageNumberRenderer(Text textElement) {
        super(textElement);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        int currentPageNumber = layoutContext.getArea().getPageNumber();
        setText(String.valueOf(currentPageNumber));
        return super.layout(layoutContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CurrentPageNumberRenderer((Text) modelElement);
    }
}
```

Visual result:

[image: result]